# css file version with jsf 1.2

Tags: java, css, jsf-1.2

In reference to the question [css file with version appending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591449/css-file-with-version-appending), is there any way to use JSF builtin resource library versioning in JSF 1.2?

The tags `<h:outputStylesheet>` and `<h:outputScript>` are not available in JSF 1.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK jsf1.2 doesn't support version appending.

For our application we have implemented this mechanism manually by means of a system property.

```
<link href="/gcdm/style/basic_#{g:getSystemProperty('cssVersion','1.0')}.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

For `g:` details you can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965432/parameterize-hcommandbutton/11966845#11966845)

Now with every release we just update the System Property and put in the new css file.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Yes, this is a nice way. Thank you for it.