# Parameterize h:commandButton

Tags: java, jsf, internationalization

I am using JSF and I would like to parameterize the text of a command button similarly to `h:outputFormat`.

Something like

```
<h:commandButton value="Text {0} some more text" [...] >
```

At the moment I am

```
<h:commandButton value="Text #{bean.value()} some more text" [...] >
```

but this makes me split all the texts stored as properties in two each time I have a parameter

```
<h:commandButton value="#{msg.textbefore} #{bean.value()} #{msg.textafter}" [...] >
```

Any hint?

Comment: What about a backing bean method that takes a message id and a list/array of params and returns the complete message string?

Comment: @MattHandy something like `#{bean.format( msg.text , bean.value() )}` which parses all the `{N}` and substitutes?

Comment: @MattHandy I could be an option, a native JSF solution would be easier but why not :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We make use of JSF 1.2 and we have defined a method in our own custom `taglib`.

```
<h:commandButton value="#{g:formatMessage('Text {0} some more text', bean.value)}" >
```

where `g:` the name space we have defined.

```
xmlns:g="http://www.client.com/product"
```

The taglib is registered in `web.xml`

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>
        PATH_TO_CUSTOM_TAGLIB;/WEB-INF/tomahawk.taglib.xml;
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

and the method is defined in the taglib as:

```
<function>
    <function-name>formatMessage</function-name>
    <function-class>com.XXX.XXX.XXX.JavaClass</function-class>
    <function-signature>java.lang.String formatMessage(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)</function-signature>
</function>
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't allow providing multiple parameters without specifying multiple functions. EL functions unfortunately doesn't support varargs.

Comment: For multiple parameters A tweak...     `<h:commandButton value="#{'Begin Text'g:formatMessage(g:formatMessage('Text {0} some more text', bean.value)'Some {0} end text', bean.value2)}" >`

Comment: True, but those message templates are usually retrieved from a bundle file, not hardcoded in the view.